# xml2 - get information from parent nodes more efficiently

Tags: r, xml, xml2

i have an xml looking like this:

```
...
<node id=1>
 <child>a</child>
 <child>b</child>
 <child>c</child>
</node>
<node id=2>
 <child>d</child>
 <child>e</child>
</node>
...
```

What I am looking for is a data.frame referring to the respective parent of the child:

```
node_id  child_text
      1           a
      1           b
      1           c
      2           d
      2           e
```

There are only 2 solutions I could think of using xml2:

(a) create a set of child nodes using xml_find_all(...) and then use a for loop to maneuver through the xml structure to get the required information. Extremely inefficient obviously.

(b) get a set of parent nodes and a set of child nodes for each . Extract the information from the parent set and count how many children each parents has. Then used rep(information, no_of_children) to fill the node_id column from above. Better but still stupid.

I assume there has to be a more efficient way? I am happy for any suggestion as I am using these approaches for over a month now while dealing with gigabites of  - highly inefficient - data structures in xml format. I am also not limited to using xml2 and can also switch to another programming language if this would drastically improve the performance. The only important part is that I would like to load the data directly into a database from there.

Answer (score 0):

Given the very generic example you gave I'd use `rvest` together with `purrr`:

```
x <- "<node id=1>
   <child>a</child>
   <child>b</child>
   <child>c</child>
  </node>
  <node id=2>
   <child>d</child>
   <child>e</child>
  </node>"


library(rvest)
library(purrr)

read_html(x) %>% 
  html_nodes('node') %>% 
  map_df(~{
    .x %>% 
      html_nodes('child') %>% 
      html_text() -> child
    data.frame(child = child, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }, .id = 'node')

#>   node child
#> 1    1     a
#> 2    1     b
#> 3    1     c
#> 4    2     d
#> 5    2     e
```

And some benchmark to compare with your methods:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(read_html(xml) %>% 
                        html_nodes('node') %>% 
                        map_df(~{
                          .x %>% 
                            html_nodes('child') %>% 
                            html_text() -> child
                          data.frame(child = child, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
                        }, .id = 'node'), columns = c('replications', 'elapsed', 'user.self'))
#>   replications elapsed user.self
#> 1          100   0.964     0.964
```

Comment: Actually this approach is a lot slower than the approaches I already pointed out:

Benchmark time for your approach: 1.45

For solution(a): 0.46

For solution (b): 0.12